Are there risks when mixing sync and async methods in one WinForms class?
I am developing a WinForms application (.Net 7), which consist of one starter form, from which with buttons the user can open a couple of different child forms, each showing charts with statistics retrieved from a MySQL database.
So far the application was synchronous, so any opened form was blocking the UI while the MySQL query was executed. I decided to make the app asynchronous, mainly to make it possible that the user is able to use the other forms (form2, form3, etc.) while a longer query is running in form1.
The thing is that the only asynchronous part of the class is the function that initiate the MySQL query and returning a datatable with the results of the query. The rest of the code is a Sub used to create the charts, which according to recommendations cannot be asynchronous.
My questions:

Are there any risks when mixing in the same WinForms class sync and async methods?
Are there any risks when more than one WinForms classes are running simultaneously, all having mixed sync and async methods? So far I haven't experienced any problems.
Is there a way to make the Sub acts asynchronously? I prefer it to be that way, because sometimes the Sub is taking more time to finish (2,3,4 sec) and the user can feel that by the blocking of the UI, while he/she is working in the other WinForms.

A simplified example of one WinForm class is shown below. There are comments describing in brief what the different lines are designed to do.
Public Class Form1

    Public Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim TabCell As New DataTable
        'TabCell is the statistical table used to build the charts

        Dim getStats As New Queries
        'Queries is a class with different functions for
        'extracting data from MySQL database

        TabCell = Await Task(Of DataTable).Run(Function() getStats.ExecQuery(parameters))
        'ExecQueryPar is a function of Queries class,
        'which returns a datatable with statistics.
        'This is done asynchronous, because query can
        'take quite a time

        Dim TabCharts As New DataTable
        'Each row of TabCharts contains the definition of one chart

        TabCharts = getStats.ExecQuery("select ChartNo,Chart_KPI_Name,KPI from config_charts")
        'Parameters for each chart definitions are retrieved from database.
        'This is done synchronous, because query is very fast

        For i As Integer = 0 To TabCharts.Rows.Count - 1
            ChartDefs.ChartsDaily(Me.Controls.Find("Chart" + TabCharts.Rows(i)("ChartNo").ToString, True).FirstOrDefault(),
                                TabCell, TabCharts.Rows(i)("Chart_KPI_Name"), TabCharts.Rows(i)("KPI"))
        Next
        'ChartDefs is a class containing code for creation of charts.
        'ChartsDaily is a Sub for a specific type of chart.
        'The empty charts were created when loading the form, so they
        'already exist. In the loop each chart is fetched by its
        'object name and ChartsDaily sub is applying parameters
        'to every charts.
        'This is done synchronous because it is a sub. But sometimes
        'chart building can take longer time, which can be felt by blocking
        'shortly the UI, while working with the other WinForms in the app.

    End Sub

End Class


The main risk is that every Await imposes a potential re-entrancy point.  Anything else in your program might try to run while you're waiting for the farmed-out routine to complete, and there's no guarantee that the form state is the same when you finish as when you started.

How does it behave? Do you know what SynchronizationContext is being used? Sometimes you need to ensure you are keeping the UI thread available.... Have you tried ConfigureAwait(false)? What .NET version?

@Craig Does this mean that any code in the class, which is not an async method and stays inbetween such methods might run before preceeding async method is finished? I can't imagine a WinForms app, which consists of methods only and there is no other code. Regarding how to make the Sub asynchronous I will try following Dim t As New Task(AddressOf ChartDefs.ChartsDaily) t.Start t.Wait. Hopefully it will work and will align properly with the other async methods.

@Grantly I am using .Net 7. I will provide more info to you but apparently async wait programming is not so easy as it is presented in some sources, so I will need to make a deeper research.

When you reach an Await, control returns to the application's message loop with a tag inserted so that it can resume execution once the called async routine finishes.  So literally anything that is accessible from the message loop might execute in that time window.  Most commonly, that would be something that would originate from a user interaction, but there are other things like a timer or a reaction to an incoming message that might also fit that description.

If you want to read more about it, I would highly recommend Stephen Cleary's articles on asynchronous programming.  It makes a lot of things easier, but there are significant pitfalls for the unwary.

This answer originates from the author of the question.
In the past month I did really many experiments related to testing whether mixing Sync and Async code will cause any issues. The result of the tests is that there were no issues at all.
Some considerations:

In my case charts are being depicted based on statistics delivered by MySQL query. I made all queries in the WinForms class to run as Async, no matter whether the query takes longer time or it is very fast by design.

In most of the cases the queries are returning a result, so they are Function, what is the best candidate for Async Await. But there are also queries, which don't return results and are Sub. In theory Subs are not good candidates for async. For this purpose I redesigned the Sub into a fake Function, which returns a dummy boolean or integer value, which is not serving any purpose in the code. Example for such queries are the creation and dropping of temporary tables, the insert into... select... statements, etc.

Very important is that while the charts are waiting to be fed with statistics during async query execution, not to be interacted with. I think this is the so called reentry points, which causes risks for the code execution and the result might be unpredictable. In my case there are 2 ways for interacting with the charts - either by right-click popup menu, which I disabled while the process of charts update is not finished. Or by triggering a second query, while the first one is still running - I avoided that by disabling the button for query start.

Regarding how to make a Sub to act asynchronously you can check here. This is another question of mine, which at the time of writing of this answer, is not answered yet, but I have some progress, which I will post once I am sure that the solution will work.


Below you can find an updated version of the code in the question with some adjustments and changes.
Public Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TabCell As New DataTable

    Dim getStats As New Queries

    TabCell = Await Task().Run(Function() getStats.ExecQuery(parameters))

    Dim TabCharts As New DataTable

    TabCharts = Await Task().Run(Function() getStats.ExecQuery("select ChartNo,Chart_KPI_Name,KPI from config_charts"))
    'Very fast query to execute, but it is better to be
    'executed Async, so that all possible to be async

    Dim ret As Boolean = False
    ret = Await Task.Run(Function() getStats.ExecQueryFakeReturn("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE ee_4g_hua.tmptab;"))
    'Query, which originally doesn't return a value and used to be a Sub
    'I made it a Function with a dummy return value

    For i As Integer = 0 To TabCharts.Rows.Count - 1
        ChartDefs.ChartsDaily(Me.Controls.Find("Chart" + TabCharts.Rows(i)("ChartNo").ToString, True).FirstOrDefault(),
                        TabCell, TabCharts.Rows(i)("Chart_KPI_Name"), TabCharts.Rows(i)("KPI"))
    Next
    'The sync Sub above should be wrapped in Async Task
    'How to do this is a matter of another thread in StackOverflow

End Sub

